# Email from action function not being send

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, actionfunction

I have below action function in vf page

```
<apex:actionFunction name="changeOwnership" action="{!changeOwnership}" rerender="changeOwnershipId" oncomplete="ownerShipChangedComplete()">
```

and in the controller I have below method

```
 public void changeOwnership() { 
    String usId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('usId');
    String userEmail = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('userEmail');
    try{       
          sendEmailMethod(usId,userEmail);
    }       
     catch(Exception e){
         System.debug(e);
     }   
    }
```

the send Email Method is below

```
public void sendEmailMethod(String usId,String userEmail){
    try{           
            System.debug('sending email');
             Messaging.singleEmailmessage Email = new Messaging.singleEmailmessage();
             email.setsubject('test');
             email.setPlainTextbody('test');
             email.setToAddresses(new String[] { usId });
             email.saveAsActivity = false;
             Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
             System.debug('###email sent');
    }
    catch(exception e){
        System.debug('cannot send email'+e);
    }
}
```

I tried to run the send email code in developer console and it works fine and I get the email but it is not working through my action function. I checked the debug statements and the send method is being called with success. 
I checked the deliveribility as well which is assigned to all emails.

Comment: Does the  URL you are using to access the VF page? contain the `usId` and `userEmail` parameters?

Comment: Yes it does. Actually I solved the problem. It was with the sending email. The user logged in from which I was sending the email was invalid. So changing the email  to valid email did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Cool. Was just checking if the URL contained the params as if it did then no need to pass them in the action function

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `usId` and `userEmail` which are the parameters to the method.

This `usId` has been used to assign `setToAddresses` which is mandatory for sending emails. That's why email functionality is not working because of missing values.

Use `<apex:param/>` and pass necessary values to controller.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="changeOwnership" action="{!changeOwnership}" rerender="changeOwnershipId" oncomplete="ownerShipChangedComplete()">
    <apex:param id="usId" name="usId" value=""/>
    <apex:param id="userEmail", name="userEmail" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: As an aside you do not need to pass the parameters if the URL already contains them.